# Triggering a Flash button with an image overlay

Tags: javascript, css, flash

I am using Google's Audio player to play an MP3 on a webpage. My issue is that I am overlaying an image on top of the the play/pause button. Yet when the image is clicked nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
<div class="center" style="width: 400px; z-index:1; visibility:hidden;">
<embed wmode="transparent" width="400" height="27" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=/sourcefile.mp3" 
src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" quality="best"
></embed>
</div>
<img style="position:absolute; left:323px; top:630px; z-index:10000;" 
src="/messages4u/2011/images/december/star-button.jpg" width="60" height="60"
alt="Play/Pause" />
```

I need to know how to trigger the flash button. I know it is possible with Javascript but I do not know how. Please provide examples.

***UPDATE:*** Here is what I have tried at this point. Per Matt H recommendation I tried this code:

```
<input type="image" disabled style="position:absolute; left:323px; top:630px;
      z-index:10000;" src="/messages4u/2011/images/december/star-button.jpg"
      width="60" height="60" alt="Play/Pause" />
```

That did not work. One thing I noticed is if I have `visibility:hidden;` the flash player will not respoind to any clicks regardless of what is over it. With that said I attempted to overlay the image using `<input>` *without* the `visibility:hidden;` and it still did not work.

I need to get this fixed if at all possible. I am willing to use another flash player that is similar as long as it works correctly and will use an mp3 like above.

Comment: Is the mp3 embedded withing the SWF file? If not, it depends on the browser, not all browsers support the use of mp3s. Try using a fallback to the .ogg format.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks - It plays fine until I try to lay the image over the flash play button. The flash needs to register that the play button is being clicked. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Aha, ok I misunderstood :) is your wmode set to transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your image is catching the click that is supposed to go to the play button. You should add a handler for your image which returns true OR calls the player's play function.

Comment: I assume you are right, any ideas on what the code would be to trigger the play button?

Comment: This guide should help you in calling a flash function from JS - http://bytes.com/topic/flash/answers/694359-how-do-i-access-flash-function-using-javascript - Even better, go for HTML5 audio feature as it can be fully manipulated using JS (but do consider the file types you want to support) - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/

Comment: I still cannot figure it out. I do not get it. And I am using flash for a few different reasons and not using HTML 5.

Comment: Do you have the source of the audio player ? You can invoke the function in flash from javascript using External Interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="image" disabled style="position:absolute; left:323px; top:630px; z-index:10000;"
      src="/messages4u/2011/images/december/star-button.jpg"
      width="60" height="60" alt="Play/Pause" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help yet that did not work =<  Other ideas? I updated my question to show what I have done.